# Video Editing issues in iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-editing, avasset

I am currently working on an iOS app which merges desired number of videos. Once the user taps the button to merge the videos, the videos are joined and then played using AVPlayer as:

```
CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;
NSInteger i;
CMTime transitionDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 1); // Default transition duration is one second.

// Add two video tracks and two audio tracks.
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTracks[2];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTracks[2];
compositionVideoTracks[0] = [self.mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
compositionVideoTracks[1] = [self.mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
compositionAudioTracks[0] = [self.mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
compositionAudioTracks[1] = [self.mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

CMTimeRange *passThroughTimeRanges = alloca(sizeof(CMTimeRange) * [self.selectedAssets count]);
CMTimeRange *transitionTimeRanges = alloca(sizeof(CMTimeRange) * [self.selectedAssets count]);

// Place clips into alternating video & audio tracks in composition, overlapped by transitionDuration.
for (i = 0; i < [self.selectedAssets count]; i++ )
{
    NSInteger alternatingIndex = i % 2; // alternating targets: 0, 1, 0, 1, ...
    AVURLAsset *asset = [self.selectedAssets objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"number of tracks %d",asset.tracks.count);

    CMTimeRange assetTimeRange;
    assetTimeRange.start = kCMTimeZero;
    assetTimeRange.duration = asset.duration;
    NSValue *clipTimeRange = [NSValue valueWithCMTimeRange:assetTimeRange];
    CMTimeRange timeRangeInAsset;
    if (clipTimeRange)
        timeRangeInAsset = [clipTimeRange CMTimeRangeValue];
    else
        timeRangeInAsset = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset duration]);

    AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    [compositionVideoTracks[alternatingIndex] insertTimeRange:timeRangeInAsset ofTrack:clipVideoTrack atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

    AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    [compositionAudioTracks[alternatingIndex] insertTimeRange:timeRangeInAsset ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

    // Remember the time range in which this clip should pass through.
    // Every clip after the first begins with a transition.
    // Every clip before the last ends with a transition.
    // Exclude those transitions from the pass through time ranges.
    passThroughTimeRanges[i] = CMTimeRangeMake(nextClipStartTime, timeRangeInAsset.duration);
    if (i > 0) {
        passThroughTimeRanges[i].start = CMTimeAdd(passThroughTimeRanges[i].start, transitionDuration);
        passThroughTimeRanges[i].duration = CMTimeSubtract(passThroughTimeRanges[i].duration, transitionDuration);
    }
    if (i+1 < [self.selectedAssets count]) {
        passThroughTimeRanges[i].duration = CMTimeSubtract(passThroughTimeRanges[i].duration, transitionDuration);
    }

    // The end of this clip will overlap the start of the next by transitionDuration.
    // (Note: this arithmetic falls apart if timeRangeInAsset.duration < 2 * transitionDuration.)
    nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, timeRangeInAsset.duration);
    nextClipStartTime = CMTimeSubtract(nextClipStartTime, transitionDuration);

    // Remember the time range for the transition to the next item.
    transitionTimeRanges[i] = CMTimeRangeMake(nextClipStartTime, transitionDuration);
}

// Set up the video composition if we are to perform crossfade or push transitions between clips.
NSMutableArray *instructions = [NSMutableArray array];

// Cycle between "pass through A", "transition from A to B", "pass through B", "transition from B to A".
for (i = 0; i < [self.selectedAssets count]; i++ )
{
    NSInteger alternatingIndex = i % 2; // alternating targets

    // Pass through clip i.
    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *passThroughInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    passThroughInstruction.timeRange = passThroughTimeRanges[i];
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *passThroughLayer = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:compositionVideoTracks[alternatingIndex]];

    passThroughInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:passThroughLayer];
    [instructions addObject:passThroughInstruction];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *fromLayer;

    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *toLayer;

    if (i+1 < [self.selectedAssets count])
    {
        // Add transition from clip i to clip i+1.

        AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *transitionInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
        transitionInstruction.timeRange = transitionTimeRanges[i];
        fromLayer = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:compositionVideoTracks[alternatingIndex]];
        toLayer = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:compositionVideoTracks[1-alternatingIndex]];


        // Fade out the fromLayer by setting a ramp from 1.0 to 0.0.
        [fromLayer setOpacityRampFromStartOpacity:1.0 toEndOpacity:0.0 timeRange:transitionTimeRanges[i]];

        transitionInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fromLayer, toLayer, nil];
        [instructions addObject:transitionInstruction];



    }

    AVURLAsset *sourceAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[self.selectedItemsURL objectAtIndex:i] options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey]];

    AVAssetTrack *sourceVideoTrack = [[sourceAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];



    CGSize temp = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(sourceVideoTrack.naturalSize, sourceVideoTrack.preferredTransform);
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(fabsf(temp.width), fabsf(temp.height));
    CGAffineTransform transform = sourceVideoTrack.preferredTransform;

    self.videoComposition.renderSize = sourceVideoTrack.naturalSize;
    if (size.width > size.height) {

        [fromLayer setTransform:transform atTime:sourceAsset.duration];
    } else {


        float s = size.width/size.height;


        CGAffineTransform new = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(s,s));

        float x = (size.height - size.width*s)/2;

        CGAffineTransform newer = CGAffineTransformConcat(new, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, 0));

        [fromLayer setTransform:newer atTime:sourceAsset.duration];
    }



}

self.videoComposition.instructions = instructions;

self.videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);



NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mergeVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

self.exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:self.mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
self.exporter.outputURL=url;
self.exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
self.exporter.videoComposition = self.videoComposition;
self.exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:self.mixComposition];
self.playerItem.videoComposition = self.videoComposition;
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
[playerLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height)];
[[[self imageView] layer] addSublayer:playerLayer];
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[player play];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkPlayEnded) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:self.playerItem];
```

I am currently facing the following issues:

1. If one video is in portrait, and other is in landscape, how i will be able to rotate the portrait video in landscape as my view is in landscape orientation but the portrait video retain its original ?
   (i am loading videos stored in the camera roll, not recording them inside my app)
2. Neglecting the above mentioned issue, if i merges any number of videos, they work fine. Once i save that new video in my library, and then load it in my app again and try to join that video with some other new video, the resolution got disturbed although both videos if played separately in the app, works really fine. How can i solve that?

(I have tried to follow the WWDC 2010 video editing tutorial, so this code is extracted from there.)

Comment: If you didn't got the solution till now let me know,I know how to fix this issue ....

Comment: @ParvezBelim Thanks for your interest. I implemented following solutions which helped me addressing the issues.
1. Whenever a user wants to add a video in project, its orientation is checked and if it isn't landscape, it is converted to landscape and then added in the project.

Comment: 2. Issue 2 was happening because of the difference in resolution of videos exported by AVExportSession and ones created by camera. SO now, they are first converted to a preselected resolution and then are added in the project, which results in all the videos in the project having same resolution and thus everything works fine.

Comment: @ParvezBelim If you have any more proper and appropriate solution, you are more than welcome to share :)

Comment: check out the answer I had given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the orientation of the video run time in above code while you create object for AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction.

The code that is to be appended to the code to fix issue is....

```
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mutableComposition duration]);
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[mutableComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction * layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];

UIImageOrientation videoAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
BOOL  isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
CGAffineTransform videoTransform = assetVideoTrack.preferredTransform;

if(videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0)
{
    videoAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight;
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if(videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0)
{
    videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft;
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}

CGFloat FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0 / assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.width;
if(isVideoAssetPortrait_)
{
    videoSize=CGSizeMake(350,400);
    FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.height;
    CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
    [layerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(assetVideoTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
}
else
{
    videoSize=CGSizeMake(assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.width,assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.height);
}
```

The above code will keep the landscape video in landscape and prevent video  being convert from portrait to landscape.

I hope this will help.Instead of first converting into proper orientation and then applying editing.If you append this code your one step will be reduced and can do both things(i.e editing & orientation) in one code and also in much quicker way.