# merge two videos in ios app still maintain the orientation of each video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, merge, video-capture

I am working on an that merges two videos, found a strange issue that when I try to merge a portrait video and a landscape video, the output result shows the landscape version of video in potrait mode, which I don't want to happen.
I am pretty sure I'm missing something fundamental in managing orientation.

My code is here :

```
NSMutableArray  *videoClipPaths=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


[videoClipPaths addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:videoBundleURL1]];
[videoClipPaths addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:videoBundleURL2]];
[videoClipPaths addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:videoBundleURL1]];

float start_time=startSeconds;
float end_time=endSeconds;




  AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionTrack2 = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    __block CMTime time = kCMTimeZero;
    __block CGAffineTransform translate;
    __block CGSize size;

for (int i=0; i<[videoClipPaths count]; i++)
{
    AVURLAsset *assetClip = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[videoClipPaths objectAtIndex:i] options:nil];
    AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrackB = [[assetClip tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVAsset *anAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[videoClipPaths objectAtIndex:i] options:nil];
    CMTime start;
    CMTime duration;
    CMTimeRange video_timeRange;
    if (i==0){
        start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0f, anAsset.duration.timescale);
        duration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(start_time, anAsset.duration.timescale);
        video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,duration);
        [compositionTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:clipVideoTrackB atTime:start error:nil];

        size = CGSizeMake(clipVideoTrackB.naturalSize.height, clipVideoTrackB.naturalSize.height);

        translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-420, 0);
        CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, clipVideoTrackB.preferredTransform);
        [compositionTrack setPreferredTransform:newTransform];
        time = CMTimeAdd(time, duration);

    }else if (i==1){
        CMTime duration = anAsset.duration;
        float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);

        start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(start_time, anAsset.duration.timescale);
        duration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, anAsset.duration.timescale);
        video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,duration);
        [compositionTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:clipVideoTrackB atTime:start error:nil];

        translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-420, 0);
        CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, clipVideoTrackB.preferredTransform);
        [compositionTrack setPreferredTransform:newTransform];
        time = CMTimeAdd(time, duration);
    }
    else if (i==2){
        CMTime duration = anAsset.duration;
        float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);

        start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(end_time, anAsset.duration.timescale);
        duration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds-start_time, anAsset.duration.timescale);
        //            duration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(anAsset.duration.timescale, anAsset.duration.timescale);
        video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(start_time, anAsset.duration.timescale),duration);
        [compositionTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:clipVideoTrackB atTime:kCMTimeInvalid error:nil];

        translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-420, 0);
        CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, clipVideoTrackB.preferredTransform);
        [compositionTrack setPreferredTransform:newTransform];
        time = CMTimeAdd(time, duration);
    }
    //        video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start,duration);

    //merge audio of video files
    AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrackB1 = [[assetClip tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    /*CMTime start1;
     CMTime duration1;
     CMTimeRange video_timeRange1;
     if (i==0){
     start1 = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, anAsset.duration.timescale);
     duration1 = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(start_time, anAsset.duration.timescale);

     }else if (i==1){
     start1 = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(start_time, anAsset.duration.timescale);
     duration1 = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(end_time-start_time, anAsset.duration.timescale);
     }
     else if (i==2){
     start1 = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(end_time, anAsset.duration.timescale);
     duration1 = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(anAsset.duration.timescale, anAsset.duration.timescale);
     }
     video_timeRange1 = CMTimeRangeMake(start,duration);*/
    [compositionTrack2 insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:clipVideoTrackB1 atTime:start error:nil];

}
```

The above code determines the time range for the 3 videos ( actually 2 videos ) but I have to embed the 2nd video inside the 1st video in the predetermined time interval.

The below code will create the mutable composition of all the assets that I'm having:

```
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *vtemp = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
vtemp.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, time);
NSLog(@"\nInstruction vtemp's time range is %f %f", CMTimeGetSeconds( vtemp.timeRange.start),
      CMTimeGetSeconds(vtemp.timeRange.duration));

// Also tried videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:compositionVideoTrack
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *vLayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction
                                                                videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:compositionTrack];


[vLayerInstruction setTransform:compositionTrack.preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
vtemp.layerInstructions = @[vLayerInstruction];

AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
videoComposition.renderSize = size;
videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,30);
videoComposition.instructions = @[vtemp];

AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
NSParameterAssert(exporter != nil);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
documentsPath=[documentsPath stringByAppendingString:@"/MergeVideos"];
```

..... the rest is saving the video to the Photos library

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246557/video-editing-issues-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

I have the Swift version. Mine one works perfectly.. Here is my one.. After hours of hours coding finally got this to work. Sorry to post the answer in Swift. Hope you find this useful.

`readyVideoURLs` is that contains all the video URLs. And you can merge any number of videos with this code.

And I'm creating square sized video.

`mainComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 600)`

```
func mergeVideos() {

        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        let compositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

        var current = kCMTimeZero
        var assetArr = [AVURLAsset]()

        let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

        for url in readyVideoURLs {
            assetArr.append(AVURLAsset(url: url))
            print("readyVideoURL vid url:- \(url)")

        }

        for asset in assetArr {
            do {
                try compositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration), of: asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)

            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }


            let instruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: compositionTrack, asset: asset)
            mainInstruction.layerInstructions.append(instruction)
            mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(current, asset.duration))
            current = CMTimeAdd(current, asset.duration)
        }


        let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
        mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
        mainComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 600)


        //add audio track
//        if let loadedAudioAsset = audioAsset {
//            let audioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: 0)
//            do {
//                try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, current),
//                                               of: loadedAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)
//            } catch _ {
//                print("Failed to load Audio track")
//            }
//        }

        let finalVideoPath = NSHomeDirectory().appending("/Documents/finalDailyVideo.mp4")
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: finalVideoPath) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: finalVideoPath)
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

        guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else { return }
        exporter.outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: finalVideoPath)
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
        exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

        saveToAlbum(mergedVidUrl: URL(string:finalVideoPath)!, exporter: exporter)

    }
```

Saving to Album

```
func saveToAlbum(mergedVidUrl : URL, exporter : AVAssetExportSession)  {
        exportFinalVideo(exporter: exporter) { (completed) in
            if completed {

                let assetLib = ALAssetsLibrary()
                assetLib.writeVideoAtPath(toSavedPhotosAlbum: mergedVidUrl, completionBlock: { (assetUrl, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.showAlert(title: "Congrats..",message: "Your daily Vlog was saved in albums", actionTitle: "Got it")
                        }
                    }

                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Getting exporter completion

```
func exportFinalVideo(exporter: AVAssetExportSession, completion:@escaping(Bool) -> ())  {
        exporter.exportAsynchronously() {

            if exporter.status == .exporting {
                print("EXPORTING...")

            } else if exporter.status == .completed {
                print("merged video exporting DONE")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                completion(true)
            } else if exporter.status == .failed {
                completion(false)
                self.showAlert(title: "Oops!", message: "Something went wrong. Video could not be created.", actionTitle: "Okay!")

            }
        }

    }
```

Video layer instructions for orientation

```
func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
        let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

        let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
        let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform: transform)

        var scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.width
        if assetInfo.isPortrait {
            scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
            instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor),
                                     at: kCMTimeZero)
        } else {
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
            var concat = assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2))
            if assetInfo.orientation == .down {
                let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
                let windowBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
                let yFix = assetTrack.naturalSize.height + windowBounds.height
                let centerFix = CGAffineTransform(translationX: assetTrack.naturalSize.width, y: yFix)
                concat = fixUpsideDown.concatenating(centerFix).concatenating(scaleFactor)
            }
            instruction.setTransform(concat, at: kCMTimeZero)
        }

        return instruction
    }

    func orientationFromTransform(transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImageOrientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
        var assetOrientation = UIImageOrientation.up
        var isPortrait = false
        if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .right
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .left
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .up
        } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .down
        }
        return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
    }
```

Comment: this did not work for me... the orientations were wrong!